# Increasing the size of a textbox in html

Tags: html, css, textbox

I am a beginner at HTML. How can I increase the size of a textbox?  I do not want 1 line of text, I want an actual box. I cannot use Javascript.

-Thank you.

Comment: Have you spent any time researching the different element types to see what is available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For multiple lines of text, you should use textarea HTML input

```
<textarea rows=4></textarea>
```

Number of rows defines how many lines, for more details look at, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea